Amplify push results in " Message: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"
I’m working on a React Native project with AWS Amplify and now whenever I try to push updates to my backend after adjusting my GraphQL schema, CloudFormation seems to bug out, leaving me with several nested stacks in an "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" state.
Here’s the main error showing up in the cli now after I attempt a push:
 ["Index: 1 State: {\"deploy\":\"waitingForDeployment\"} Message: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete"]

What the CloudFormation console is telling me:
My auth stack and the root stack both show "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" in red, meaning they didn't work? Not exactly sure what this means and what to do moving forward.
Cloudformation Screenshot
Last time I came across this error, I removed the api and added it back, but now it seems the issue may also have to do with the auth stack as well. Any help or advice on CloudFormation and these issues would be greatly appreciated.
amplify push --force and amplify push --iterative-rollback didn’t resolve the issue.
Manually triggering "continue update rollback" and "cancel update stack" options which are greyed out in the AWS CloudFormation console.
Reverting to older commits and re-pushing, which have not been successful.
